# WordPress: Search form submission with no term doesn't use search.php. How can I get it to?

Tags: wordpress, templates, search

I have a WordPress site, and I noticed that if I submit the search form without entering a term it the URL is "http://example.com/?s=" but it uses the index.php template instead of the search.php template. I would like it to still use the search.php file displaying no results. Or, I would like it to redirect to the front page (which is a static page). How can I accomplish either of these? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean if you search blank, it will redirect you to the index.php ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy shows that search requests should be rendered using the search.php template. However, when the form is submitted without a term (GET request to "http://example.com/?s="), the search.php template is not used. Instead the index.php template is used.

Comment: I would also like an answer on this. Pretty dumb move to render index.php if no search is entered. Blows the mind!